# Cannot find shared object in /usr/lib

Tags: linux

Im trying to install ginac on a centOS 6.5 system. But run into strange problem that the installation cannot find the file libcln.so.6 even though I've installed the packaged and file exists in /usr/lib.

What is going on? Any Idea what I should do?

Best,
Anders

Answer (score 0):

If specified library is installed then

```
ldconfig -p | grep libcln.so.6
```

will give show it. Else you need to execute

```
ldconfig
```